# CSS Class of a multi-lingual front-page

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

In Drupal 7, in the body tag of my English home page, I see the following CSS classes (among others): html, front.

I added a French translation for this home page by clicking on the "translate" link. The body tag of my French home page has the following CSS classes (among others): html, not-front.

For the French version, how do I substitute the CSS class "not-front" with "front"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this in the preprocess_html function.

You should take a look at the i18n module, which allows you to have different frontages for each language, which could be an alternative (and better) way of solving the problem.